# Create Comma-separated values file from file path

Tags: python, csv

I am using python to create a `CSV`(Comma-separated values) file. It contains the path and all file in folder. With file in different folder, it is separated by comma and then the number of its folder without character. For example, I have image `1.pgm` that stores in folder `s14`. Then the CSV format looks like

```
at/s14/1.pgm;14
```

In which,  `at/s14/1.pgm` is full path to file `1.pgm` and `14` is number (called label) that get from its folder `s14`. Could you help me implement it by python. I tried with that code but it does not work for my task

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import os
import re
import sys



SEPARATOR = ';'
CSV_FILE_PATH = 'output.csv'



if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "usage: create_csv <base_path>"
        sys.exit(1)

    path = sys.argv[1]

    # only folders in specified folder
    folders = filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir(path))

    with open(CSV_FILE_PATH, 'w') as csv_file:
        for folder in folders:
            # folder path
            folder_path = os.path.join(path, folder)

            # extracting number
            match = re.match(r's(\d+)', folder) # s\d+ is the pattern of your folder name, for example s20
            if match is not None:
                number = match.group(1)

                # loop for files within the folder
                for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
                    # full file path
                    filepath = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)

                    # writing result
                    line = SEPARATOR.join((filepath, number))
                    csv_file.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: Nothing in output file,sir. Let see the expected ouput file. Assume than at folder contains s14,s20....And I only call python.exe make_folder.py at